# Which linux folders to put on an SSD drive

Tags: linux, ssd

I will be buying a SSD drive soon and I read that putting the swap partition in there would wear the drive down.

Is there something else that I should put on a different drive?

What about the /dev and /proc folders? I see a lot of file system activity in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Directories to Map to SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/251075/linux-directories-to-map-to-ssd)

Answer (score 3):

- `/tmp` is a good choice because temporary files are often written and read by programs, not for persistent storage, but for storage of information that will be used while the program is running. Putting `/tmp` on a fast disk (or even creating a RAM disk if you have the memory) will give you a performance boost.
- `/etc` is also a good choice because `/etc` tends to be configuration files that are read often but written rarely. This means that these configuration files can be read quickly, but you won't suffer much drive wear (though the extent of this for writing often is debated, and can be amortized through wear leveling)

Basically, anything that you are going to read more than you write is a good option because it won't wear on the drive. You should also enable wear leveling to lessen the impact of this even for many-write situations.

As chrisaycock points out, you should look through the [Filesystem Layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and think about what works for you. Personally, I put pretty much everything (though, I don't use swap) except for `/home` on an SSD and that is just due to space restrictions.

`/dev` and `/proc` are virtual filesystems which reside in kernel memory, so the writes *shouldn't* matter here (I could be completely wrong that the writes don't actually hit the disk, so if someone more knowledgable could weigh in, I would appreciate it. `/proc` might make copies of the binaries you load for what it's worth…).

Comment: Thank you!. I should probably ask it in another question, but what do you use instead of swap?

Comment: 4GiB of RAM. I haven't ever used it all, and the boot is so fast that I don't bother with hibernation, so I didn't see a point to having a swap partition.

Comment: `/proc` is not backed by a real partition at all - it's not *possible* to put it on any particular disk.  `/dev` can be either a real partition (in which case it is read-mostly, like `/etc`) or a `tmpfs`, which doesn't live on disk either.

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with Linux's [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). For example, the *proc filesystem* (`/proc`) and the device files (`/dev`) are created by the OS to look like files; they reside in memory and not on the disk anyway.

To answer your question, feel free to put anything that's **actually a file** on the SSD. That includes binaries, configs, logs, etc. The *swap*, for example, is created by the virtual memory system and is not a file, at least as far as you're concerned anyway.