# Linux Directories to Map to SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, ubuntu-10.10

I am going to do a reinstall of Ubuntu on my workstation and have an SSD in there. Which directories would you map to the SSD during installation for the following criteria:

- Rather not blast it with writes
- Don't want to put /home there. I know this will probably give me the best increase in speed but don't want the risk of my data being on an a consumer MLC (even with backups)

Answer (score 8):

If you're not installing software constantly then I'd map:

```
/bin
/sbin
/usr
/lib
/opt (if you have it)
/etc
```

to the SSD.

These directories are going to be read many more times than written to (as writes only occur to these locations when software is installed).

Comment: +1, All very fine choices. Personally I'd also add `/var` to it, but that fails the 'blast with writes' criteria.

Comment: Keep in mind that out-of-the-box, MySQL puts its database files in /var. How that fits into SSD use scenario, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the directories listed by [superdupersheep](https://superuser.com/questions/251075/linux-directories-to-map-to-ssd/251081#251081):

```
/bin
/sbin
/usr
/lib
/opt (if you have it)
/etc
```

I'd also add `/boot`, and also make the SSD the boot drive since this is where the linux kernel will live.